# "I have to face" or "I have been facing" and what is the difference?

Tags: american-english, syntactic-analysis, canadian-english, is-it-a-sentence, sentence-meaning

> I have to face the real face of life.

Is this sentence correct?

Or should I say:

> I have been facing the real face of life.

What I am trying to say is that I have been forced to do this.

Comment: To indicate you are forced to do it, use "I have to face".

Comment: *I have to* means you have an obligation to and you are ready to in the near future. If you have been forced to, then you have been doing it recently.

Comment: 'I have to face the facts as they are' or 'I have to face reality' avoids the incongruity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the constructions **I have to face...** and **I have been facing...** are grammatical but different in meaning and usage. *I have been facing...* is an example of *the present perfect continuous tense* and mainly to mean an action started at a certain time in the past, continued up to the present and it may still continue to the future. Whereas, *I have to face...* shows an action (an obligation) which I have to do in the near future. **Have/has + to infinitive** is somewhat equal to **must + bare infinitive**.

Detailed explanations and examples can be had from [learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org](http://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar-vocabulary/grammar-videos/have-must-and-should-obligation-and-advice)

Answer (score 0):

The question you need to answer is, did you face the real face of life yet?

> I **have to** face the real face of life.

"Have to" is referring to something that you need to do in the future. Did something just occur that will force you to face the real face of life now?

> I **have been** facing the real face of life.

"Have been" refers to something you already are experiencing. Have you already been forced to face the real face of life?

---

On an unrelated side note, "face the real face of life" is somewhat of an awkward phrase to use, and I would consider rewording that part.

Comment: Do you mean (I have been facing) express more that I have forced from long time ago and still and will be or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Using "Have to" means you do not have any choice. Using "Have been" means that you have already been doing since a long time.

1. If you are going to be forced (in the future) then you use "I have to face the real face of life."
2. If you are forced (presently) then you use "I am facing the real face of life"
3. If you are already forced and continue being forced (past continuous) then you use "I have been facing the real face of life"

In all this you still seem to have a choice of walking away therefore you can use the word "force" itself.

1. I am forced to face the real face of life.
2. I have been forced to face the real face of life.
3. I am being forced to face the real face of life.

Comment: Your welcome @user251527